# Upgraded to Raring Ringtail 13.04, but not every package did?

Tags: 12.10, updates, 13.04

I just noticed while looking at a bunch of packages in Synaptic that some are stuck at their quantal version although in their package settings shows a raring version, how do I make sure these packages update to their raring version without having to go one by one?

Updated from Quantal Quetzal 12.10 64 bit to Raring Ringtail 13.04 64 bit via "update-manager -d"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's normal because of the development cycle. They will change to 13.04 once the final release arrives. I would also recommend making sure all repositories are activated in the **Software & Updates** app (Found in Dash):

[image]

[image]

NOTE - Since this is a development version, you will sometimes get when doing an update an error. Maybe it will say "Bad checksum", maybe "Repository not available" or maybe other errors related to repositories. Do not worry about this. Simply wait a while, I normally wait an hour before doing the update process again. It happens a lot on Development versions before they are released. A lot of repositories are updated on a daily basis. So the whole update system might show an error while you do the update.

Comment: Ok I got scared for a moment that maybe something screwed itself up during upgrade and that I was looking at a reinstall, thank you. Also I have already checked all the extra repositories before so that isn't a issue.

Comment: @Raansu going to update the answer to mention something about this.